# PHP: Wrapping built-in function (filter_input) and optional parameters

Tags: php, filter-input

So, I know that with PHP you can define optional parameters ([StackOverflow Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187964/how-do-i-set-an-optional-parameter-in-php-after-the-first-optional-parameter)).

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
function myFunc($a, $b, $c, $type, $variable_name, $filter, $options)
{
   $value = filter_input($type, $variable_name, $filter, $options);

   //Do something with $a, $b, $c, and $value
}
```

Since I am passing in parameters that pertain to the built in function of `filter_input` I know that $filter and $options are optional parameters, and to make them optional I would simply assign them a default value. But, I'm not sure what that default value should be. My guess is that $filter should default to `FILTER_DEFAULT`, which makes sense, but I can not find any information as to what $options should default to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default both $filter and $options to NULL.  They are optional for `filter_input()` as well, so why assign them a value when `filter_input()` will do it for you?  If PHP were ever to update the defaults for the function then you'd still be current, too.

Your function would look like this:

```
function myFunc($a, $b, $c, $type, $variable_name, $filter=NULL, $options=NULL)
{...
```

Comment: So if I do filter_input($type, $variable_name, null, null) that will be the same as filter_input($type, $variable_name) ?

Comment: That's exactly equivalent.  You either spell out the NULL values or you imply them, but either way you pass NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on the [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) method suggests that the expected value is an integer so it would probably be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As the options argument for the [filter_input](http://www.php.net/filter_input) function is er.. optional and can be either an array or a bitmask, so I suspect using...

```
function myFunc($a, $b, $c, $type, $variable_name, $filter, $options=null) {
    ...
```

..would be ideal, unless there's an application specific reason for doing otherwise.