# PHP Call a function with default parameter, but in the middle of parameter list?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to skip parameters that have default values in a php(5) function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579331/is-it-possible-to-skip-parameters-that-have-default-values-in-a-php5-function)

Lets say this is my function :

```
function myFunc($a ,$b = 'ball',$c = 'cat')
{
   echo "$a $b $c" ;
}



 myFunc("apple");   // output :  "apple ball cat"
 myFunc("apple","box"); // output : "apple box cat"
```

How can I call `myFunc` with default parameter for `$b`, eg

```
myFunc("apple", SOMETHING_HERE , "cow" ); // output : "apple ball cow"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that by setting the default values in the prototype of the function :

```
function myFunc($a ,$b = 'ball',$c)
{
   echo "$a $b $c" ;
}
```

But there is a workaround :

```
function myFunc($a ,$b = null,$c = null)
{
   if ($b === null)
      $b = 'ball';
   if ($c === null)
      $c = 'cat';

   echo "$a $b $c" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) function and some special indication that a default value should be used (for example, pass `NULL`):

```
function myFunc() {
 $params = func_get_args();
 $defaults = array('apple', 'ball', 'cow'); //your default values
 foreach ($params as &key => &$value) {
   if ($value === NULL) $value = $defaults[$key];
 }

myFunc('apple', NULL, 'cow');
```

Having said that, I think it's not the best practice to do things like that. You should look into your function design once again - maybe you just need to refactor something slightly so it would be more intuitive.